# Is there a Ubuntu-next Server beta image available for download?

Tags: server, downloads, 16.04

The daily images are here: 
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

But these are only the desktop images.  Anyone know whether downloads are provided for the corresponding server image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/ The server has a slightly different link. The server release does not have a "live dvd" version.

```
xenial-server-amd64.iso         04-Mar-2016 06:57  749M  Server        
install image for 64-bit PC (AMD64) computers (standard download)

xenial-server-i386.iso          04-Mar-2016 06:59  738M  Server 
install image for 32-bit PC (i386) computers (standard download)
```

Comment: Server images never have the "live" environment which we find in desktop ISOs.

Comment: Maybe you didn't get what I wanted to say: the `daily-live` are ISOs supporting "live" environments, the `daily` ISOs don't. It's not about how they are generated, but what they have.

Comment: ah wait. I am slow today (had a migraine today). Forget I asked :D